# How can i create 6 tables, each 3 next to each other

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create 6 tables, each 3 next to each other that would look **exactly** like this 
[image]
and this is my code so far

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & CR & NCR \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{something} & CR & 340 & 22 \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & NCR & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{94.24\%} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & CR & NCR \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{something} & CR & 340 & 22 \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & NCR & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{94.24\%} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & CR & NCR \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{something} & CR & 340 & 22 \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & NCR & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{94.24\%} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%


}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following 
[image]

and here are the issues I cant work through:

1. I'm having trouble placing the word "Actual" the way it is, as in vertically
2. I can't seem to recreate the borders
3. I also can't recreate the small distance between each table
4. I'm also having an issue creating a caption for each table (as shown in the picture) while maintaining the same Label for all 6 tables
5. I also want to remove the word "TABLE IV"
6. How can I place the rest of the 6 tables (the remaining 3) under the initial 3 I've provided while keeping them in the same `\begin{table}[]` `\end{table}`  Environment

How can I fix the above issues?

please note that my document has a double column layout.

Comment: Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document. We need to know used document class as well page layout. From image can be concluded, that you like to have six sub tables in `table` float environment.

Comment: @Zarko thank you. I extended my code fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MWE (Minimal Working Example) solve almost all your requirements :-)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}   
%    \caption{}          % if you want to have a common caption of the table, remove %
%    \label{tab:my-table} % remove % if you will use c+"\caption"
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
    \centering                % center table in "sibtable" environment
    \caption{404-2}           % caption of sub table
    \label{subtab:my-table-a} % label for referencing od sub table
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill             % push subtables away
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{404-5-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{404-10-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}

\bigskip    % additiona vertical space between rows with subtables
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{210-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
 \centering
   \caption{210-5-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{210-10-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{something}
    & CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
Accuracy
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \midrule
MSE &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: your table can not be fit in one column. Therefore i suggest to  use `table*` float environment. It is always on the top of the next page after point on insertion in document text.

**addendum:**
MWE according to your comment:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}   
%    \caption{}
%    \label{tab:my-table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{404-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
           & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{404-5-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
           & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{404-10-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
           & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{210-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
           & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
 \centering
   \caption{210-5-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.31\linewidth}
\centering
    \caption{210-10-2}
    \label{subtab:my-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \hline
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Predicted} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &       & CR    & NCR  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{something}}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& CR    & 340   & 22 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}& NCR   & 27 & 461 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\SI{94.24}{\%}}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MSE}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{0.11517}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

- to the code of the fist MWE are added comments, which explain meaning of code parts responsible for caption and placement tables in `subtable` environment`and their placement in`table*` environment
- if you like to have table on the bottom of the same page (if there is enough space for table), than all what you need to do is:

  - in preamble load the `stfloats` package by `usepackage{stfloats}`
  - add placement option (`b` for bottom`or`t` for the top of page):

```
\begin{table*}[b]
...
\end{table*}
```

for table on the bottom of a page or

```
\begin{tablee*}[t] 
...
\end{table*}
```

for table on the top of a page.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve all my issues but it comes extremely close, so lemme list the things that it didn't solve
1- The vertical borders next to "CR" and "NCR" arent there
2- The word "something" isn't placed vertically
3- the tables span the entire document's width and i only want it to span a column's width

Comment: @Zyzzx, vertical rules doesn't work well rules from `booktabs` (your first image is very ugly), i will not reccomed to use it. (ii) if you persist to have them, than replace all rules with`hline` and add `|` on appropriate space in column specifications. The same is valid for rotating text. I doubt that for its lenght is enough vertical space in table. I will added what you desired to have asap.

Comment: i will wait for your edited code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zyzzx, any news?

Comment: sorry for the late response. ok so the tables are accurate but for some reason, they were put into their own separate page rather than how yours appeared.

Comment: so I removed the \lipsum but when I did that, the tables were moved ahead by one page which isn't the page I want it in. but when I had \lipsum it was in the right page

Comment: i also edited (or attempted at least) to edit your MWE to hold the values i actually want within my table.

Comment: floats `figure*` and `table*` always appear on zthe top of the next page after point of their inserting in text.  I emphasize this in *Note* in my answer. If you like to have it on the bottom of the same page (if there is enough space for it) you can do this by help of the package `stfloats`.

Comment: ok, can you show me how to use the "stfloats" Package. do the tables have the same \label because I noticed that every sub table has its own label but i actually want them to have 1 \label that references all of them at once. and can you tell me which number controls the space between the tables so I can maybe tinker with them and try to have the tables laid out as I initially wanted them?

Comment: @Zyzzx, this is new question. I'm convinced, that i answered on your question. Comments are not place for new question. Here they are not visible well to others who can help you.

Comment: actually in my initial question I asked "I'm also having an issue creating a caption for each table (as shown in the picture) while maintaining the same Label for all 6 tables" in number 4. I would also like to simply know which number you have placed in your code that controls the spaces between the tables? since you were the one that provided the code itself.

Comment: @Zyzzx, as you can see from code, the tables are inside `subtable` which are spaced by `\hfill` which push them away (insert between maximal available space). Inside `subtable` tables are centered. tables are inside. If you like to have common caption for all sub tables (in your question is request not have it, so I comment it), uncomment `\caption{...}` (and label, which belong to it) and write in it your caption text.  see edited answer.

Comment: @Zyzzx, now is time that you accept answer (by clicking on the check mark on the top left side of answer). So far you not accept any of received ....

Comment: as soon as I check the answer, of course, I will. Don't worry.